# Print a document with code need

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a NotePad-like program. For the print and print preview I have a problem.

Here is the code:

```
private void imprimerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument prntDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();           
}

private void aperçuavantimpressionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintPreviewDialog preview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    prntDoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(prntDoc_PrintPage);
    preview.Document = prntDoc;
    if (preview.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        prntDoc.Print();
    }
}
```

I get an error saying prntDoc doesn't exist in this context.

I need help please!

Comment: You need to learn about the "Scope" of objects. That variable is not within the scope of the aperçuavantimpressionToolStripMenuItem_Click function. Check out this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: Variables in C# are limited in scope to the brackets in which they are defined. In your case, that means the `aperçuavantimpressionToolStripMenuItem_Click` method.

Comment: The error is right, it doesn't exist. It is out of scope and is only visible in your imprimerToolStripMenuItem_Click Method. If you need to access it outside of the method make it a class/method scoped variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is here:

```
private void imprimerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument prntDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();           
}
```

the variable is confined to this scope(the imprimerToolStripMenuItem_Click method),you should do this:

```
//know the variable is declared in the class scope.
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument prntDoc;
private void imprimerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prntDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `prntDoc` in the method `imprimerToolStripMenuItem_Click`. Therefore, it's only available in that method, not in `aperçuavantimpressionToolStripMenuItem_Click`.

I suspect you should just move the code that creates `prntDoc` into the method where you use it.

Comment: *Move it where you use it* is the best advice of the answers posted here. Suggestions to create an implicit private variable for use by all methods of the class (i.e. the form) are heavy-handed IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to refer to prntDoc which you have declared in the method above, if you want to refer to prntDoc then you need to call in the method where you have declared it move this line

```
   System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument prntDoc = new    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
```

into your method

```
    aperçuavantimpressionToolStripMenuItem_Click
```